# combine queries for 2 mysql tables

Tags: mysql

I am relatively new to complex Mysql queries. I have this situation where I want to combine 2 queries

Table A has list of all the names that I want to uniqify and use to search for fields in table B.

```
Table A

id user count
1  sam  23423
2  don  123
3  tony 44
4  don  12
5  don  1
6  mia  2

Table B
user itemsold quantity
sam  item1    8
sam  item2    77
sam  item3    1
sam  item4    2
don  item8    1
don  item7    2
mia  item9    1
mia  item6    3
```

I would like to do something like this

```
for unique(A.user)
  if B.user == A.user
    SELECT B.itemsold ORDER BY B.quantity DESC LIMIT 2
```

I can get unique A.user and can query table B separately, but am not able to combine these 2 queries together.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to apply the limit on each user, or on the query as a whole? Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: The limit is on how many I can select from Table B. Its the latest mysql version.

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: I have tried select distinct(A.user), B.itemsold from A, (SELECT B.itemsold ORDER BY B.quantity DESC LIMIT 2 WHERE A.user == B.user). But it complains that A.user is unknown

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JOIN SELECT query to combine information from more than one MySQL table. With JOIN, the tables are combined side by side, and the information is retrieved from both tables.

Check this link this might help you 
https://www.dummies.com/programming/databases/combine-information-from-multiple-mysql-tables-with-join/

Comment: Thanks, Gus. I did try that, but unsuccessfully. Let me retry.